# jQuery word counting not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

**Hello there**

I'm trying to build a jQuery word counter, but almost everyone out there do not work with special characters like `æ, ø, å, ö`.... but these characters are **LETTERS** in my country **NOT** special characters.

---

This was the first counter I tried: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-count-words-textarea-input/

It worked OK, but it didn't worked with there letters above.

So I have tried to build one my self:

### http://jsfiddle.net/EcHBP/

I had to build it, so it also was counting special characters, else it wouldn't work.
Microsoft Word's word-counter also do this, so it doesn't bother me.

But now there's some other problems:

**1:** If I typing some text, hit enter, and typing some more text, it doesn't count that.

**2:** If I hit the space-button and then hit enter, it counts like there is a word.

This is very annoyoing!

I have also tried to replacing the `split(" ")` with `match(/\s+/gi)`, but that didn't do the trick.

Can someone please help me?
I'm I doing it all in the wrong way?

Comment: how are these characters displayed? By direct input or with htmlentities like `&Aring;` or even with html unicode like `&#197;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the newline with a space like this

```
var matches = $(field).val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,' ').split(" ");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EcHBP/1/)

Comment: Damnit Anton don't you have better things to do than to answer stuff before me? ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you replace all your returns with a space before you count, you should be fine.

```
text.replace(/[\n\r]/g, ' ') // Replaces all returns in text with a space
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your jsfiddle to work without your issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/gL6FY/1/

I added trim to remove empty lines and spaces at the end of the line. And I used a regex to remove spaces on multiple lines.

```
var matches = $(field).val().trim().split(/\s/gm);
```

Comment: Also a great answer. Now I do not know what to those XD

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code like this :

```
var matches = $(field).val().split(/[ \n\r]/);
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SujithPS/9nqLL/)**

Problem with your code :

It was counting all the characters seperated by space .

But new line is different character , count that too.

Comment: Also a very great answer :D